# Camera não funciona

Tags: android, android-camera

Tentei acessar a câmera do celular, funcionou 3 vezes, depois a tela ficou preta (Print abaixo) na API 24, testei ela em um celular com a API 22 e deu certo, com a API 24 não, alguém sabe como resolver isso?

```
public class fotos extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private ImageView ivPhoto;
    private Button btTakeaaPhoto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotos);

        ivPhoto = findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        btTakeaaPhoto = findViewById(R.id.btTakeaPhoto);;

        btTakeaaPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //config.showProgress(true, progressBar, context);
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Print de como a câmera fica antes de fechar e voltar para activity anterior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tela fica assim por alguns segundos e depois a câmera fecha e retorna à ativity.

O aplicativo não para de funcionar, ele apenas abre a tela da câmera, fica preto, e depois de alguns segundos ele fecha, não dá nenhuma execption, já olhei no logcat.

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

O ocorrido não é por causa de falta de permissão, já olhei nas configurações do app, elas já foram dadas.

Comment: O celular estava pousado em cima da mesa? :)

Comment: Que informação aparece no *Logcat* quando a activity fica preta ?

Comment: @White não kkkkkkkkkk

Comment: @Isac acabei de resolver, eu reiniciei meu celular e funcionou '-' , mais informações: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869615/camera-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz funcionar e você sabe como? Eu reiniciei o celular, e como eu descobri isso? Eu tentei usar a função da câmera do WhastApp e me mostrou a mensagem que não era possível acessar a câmera naquele momento, que era para eu reiniciar, então depois disso, magicamente funcionou. WWWTTFFFF -

Mais informações sobre a pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869615/camera-does-not-work/49876766#49876766)